# When do sunchokes "bolt"?

Tags: sunchoke

Is there a particular time of the year that sunchokes bolt in order to get them to get more energy production before they die in the fall? If yes, how should I promote more springtime growth?

Comment: It turns out what I mean is accelerated growth, but I don't know what that term is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bolting refers to plants going to seed.  So, in that situation they normally put all their growth into flowers and not tubers.  So, if anything, you're supposed to cut the flowers off to divert energy into tuber production.

Comment: What term am I thinking of for accelerated growth then?

Comment: Growth occurs during summer time?

Comment: yes, the taller the plant is, the more they seem to produce (or at least that's what the videos I saw showed).

Comment: like anything, you need lots of good quality soil with sun and tlc if you want good returns from your plants